# Delphi - deferring assignment to an out parameter

Tags: delphi, pointers, rtti, out

In Delphi, suppose I have a method with a (much simplified) signature like this:

```
procedure abc( const prop1:string; const arg1:TValue; const prop2:string; 
  out arg2:TValue );
```

I'm building a TList<PPropValPair> of records like this using the parameters provided:

```
type
  TPVPType = (ptIn, ptOut);
  PPropValPair = ^TPropValPair;
  TPropValPair = record
    io   : TPVPType;
    prop : string;     // property name
    iVal : TValue;     // input value
    oVar : Variant;    // <-- how to save for later use???  Variant? TValue? 
  end;
```

(On the face of it, this example looks silly. Again, it's quite simplified just to communicate the problem.)

At run-time, I want to stuff all of the input values ival (where io=ptIn) into each public property 'prop' in a class, call a class method, then extract the values of all public properites 'prop' (where io=ptOut) into oVar.

The input side is working fine using RTTI.

However, I need to somehow save a REFERENCE to the output vars in oVar so I can save the value of the associated properties after the class method has been called.

I'm not assigning anything to arg2 directly. Rather, I'm saving a reference to arg2 and assigning the value indirectly later on.

The trick is ... I don't want to have to do any additional annotations of the output parameters in abc(...).

In C++, you can declare a parameter as a 'reference' by prepending it with '&'.  So in C++ terms this might be defined roughly as:

```
procedure abc( arg1 : TValue; &arg2 : TValue );
```

Later, you can refer to &arg2 and it's using a POINTER to the object.  But in calling the function, you just say:

```
abc( somevar1, somevar2 );
```

somevar1 is passed by value, and somevar2 is passed by reference. Inside the function, I can save somevar2 in a reference var, then later on assign a value to it via the pointer (if it's a string) by saying &arg2ref = 'abc'.

I'm guessing there's a way to do this in Delphi, either with a Variant as the oVar type, or using RTTI, or something else.  I just haven't figured out the magic combination of pieces yet.  (I just don't use pointers very often in Delphi.)

Maybe I need to save a raw pointer in oVar along with the type (say, oType), and cast a value through the pointer to save the property's value?

I'm hoping someone here might have some clear ideas.

BTW, I'm using Delphi XE3.

Answer (score 3):

Use a pointer. It doesn't have to (and indeed shouldn't) be a "raw" pointer. Use a typed pointer, `PValue`. Pass in a `PValue` to your function, and then store that in `oVal`, which you should also declare a a `PValue`. Use `@` to create a pointer, and `^` to dereference.

I would not recommend passing `arg2` by reference. Although you can still use `@` on it to get a pointer to the original variable passed to `abc`, the reference parameter disguises the fact that the variable needs to remain available indefinitely. Instead, declare `arg2` as `PValue` so it's more obvious to the caller that indirection is involved.

```
// declaration
procedure abc(...; arg2: PValue);

// call
abc(..., @somevar2);
```

Comment: So what would the signature and call look like with PValue?

The scope of all these variables is relatively limited - sometimes just a few lines in a procedure, sometimes a dozen or two. I'm not concerned about lifetime of the references, although it's good to know.

Comment: The ultimate target assignment looks generally like this:

   arg^.oVar := aProp.GetValue(thisForm);

aProp is a TValue. How do I get that into oVar if it's a PValue?

Comment: Consider reading the [documentation about pointers and pointer types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Pointers_and_Pointer_Types).

Comment: I'd prefer to avoid using the @ on the out vars in the function call. I've found that the documentation on pointers isn't very helpful when interacting with RTTI stuff.

Comment: Suit yourself. The documentation applies equally well to `TValue` as it does to a `PValue` with the `^` operator applied to it, so the specific place you use `@` will have no effect on where and how you use RTTI.

Comment: The problem is I either get a compiler error or a run-time error trying to assign the TValue to a PValue. The PValue seems to be untyped. I haven't been able to come up with a combination that works.

Comment: The purpose of using the TValue is it's like a variant in that it figures out the type itself. But saving through an untyped pointer means you have to cast it to something, and we don't know at run-time what that is. A TValue assignment (on the left) would figure it out, but the PValue cannot -- it wants a hard cast, which negates the purpose of having the TValue.  Maybe there's a way for the TValue to force a write through the pointer? (eg, the Make method? Or something similar in TValue? I'm not that familiar with TValues to be sure.)

Comment: Further research suggests I need to use TValue.ExtractRawData(thePValue); -- I'll try this and report back.

Comment: I never said to use an untyped pointer. Use a typed pointer; namely, `PValue`. The thing a `PValue` variable points at will behave identically in every way to a variable of type `TValue`. To get a `TValue` from a `PValue`, simply apply the `^` operator to it, just like you would apply the `*` operator in C. You've already demonstrated knowledge of that operator in a previous comment. You only have to make one change to apply the `^` operator to `oVar`: `arg^.oVar^ := aProp.GetValue(thisForm)`.